# Embed Chatter LWC

Tags: chatter

We can display chatter feed for a particular Record using `<forceChatter:feed type="Record" subjectId="{!v.recordId}"/>` in aura components.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, it doesn't seem like there is an equivalent of `<forceChatter:feed>` for LWC.

So, you might have to build a lightning web component to display the chatter feed, by utilizing the Connect API or REST API.

Alternate approach would be to embed the lightning web component in a parent Aura component and use `<forceChatter:feed>` within this parent component.